# Moving contents of a directory to another

Tags: command-line, find, mv

I want to move all the contents including files and sub directories from `/home/storage_new/nidhal/foldertest/` to `/home/storage_new/nidhal/foldertest1/`.

When I use the command ...

```bsh
while true; do
    find /home/storage_new/nidhal/foldertest/ -mtime +3 -exec mv -t /home/storage_new/nidhal/foldertest1/ {} + 2>/dev/null
    sleep 300
done
```

... it is creating `foldertest` inside `foldertest1` like `../foldertest1/foldertest/ContentInside`. I only want the contents of `foldertest` inside `foldertest1`  like `../foldertest1/ContentInside`

What modification should I make to my command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command will create an error for each and every file and directory inside `foldertest`, because you move the whole directory including contents first and then copy all files inside, that then don't exist anymore.

You don't see the errors, because you send all error messages to `/dev/null`  with `2>/dev/null`.

Also, it won't care about the `-mtime +3` constraint for the contents of the directory.

---

If you **don't** need that constraint, you can use a simple `mv -t TARGET SOURCE/*`.

---

If you need the constraint, it is a bit more complex, as you need to `mv` every file and create it's target directory, you can use `find -type f`:

```bsh
cd /home/storage_new/nidhal/foldertest/
find . -type f -mtime +3 -exec sh -c '
    for f; do
        t=/home/storage_new/nidhal/foldertest1/${f%/*}
        mkdir -p "$t"
        mv -v -t "$t" "$f"
    done
' find-sh {} +
```

Delete empty directories afterwards:

```bsh
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

Comment: My folder is quite large, that's why I'm using find and exec

Comment: Adding * to `while true; do
    find /home/storage_new/nidhal/foldertest/* -mtime +3 -exec mv -t /home/storage_new/nidhal/foldertest1/ {} + 2>/dev/null
    sleep 300
done` helped me achieve the objective. Thanks

Comment: But note, that won't work well, because it moves files inside subdirectories regardless of their age.

Comment: So the age will be applicable only to the immediate directory level after `foldertest` ?

Comment: exactly. I updated my answer.

Comment: Hi @pLumo, could you please tell me what does this mean `${f%/*}`? Thanks

Comment: This gives the path to the file, same `dirname`

Comment: What does f% do? What's the purpose of %? Thank you

Comment: Check [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) --> `${parameter%word}`